# when click my button app is stop and error in android java

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm new in android development and am getting this errors when click my "getir" button. It error after work. How to solve this issue

my code code:

```
public  void getir(View view)
{
cursor = myData.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM kolonVeri", null);
    int gunIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("gun");
    int vtarihIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("vTarih");
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor != null)
        {
         System.out.println("VARDİYA: " + cursor.getString(gunIx));
         System.out.println("TARİH: " + cursor.getString(vtarihIx));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

}
```

error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hakannacar.vardiyam, PID: 19541
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    om.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A returned Cursor (e.g. as from rawQuery) will not be null, the check for null is useless and as shown in this case dangerous.

Rather you should be checking the Cursor `move???` methods to see if they return true.

The actual issue is that you end up trying to retrieve data for the 5th row (Index 4) when there are only 4 rows (size), as the check for `!= null` will always be true, so the loop continues beyond the 4th row.

As such your code could be :-

```
public  void getir(View view)
{
    cursor = myData.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM kolonVeri", null);
    int gunIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("gun");
    int vtarihIx = cursor.getColumnIndex("vTarih");
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         System.out.println("VARDİYA: " + cursor.getString(gunIx));
         System.out.println("TARİH: " + cursor.getString(vtarihIx));
    }
}
```

Comment: A returned cursor can be null.  The check where he has it is useless, as by then he's already derefeneced it.

Comment: @GabeSechan well bless my little white cotton sokcs. I never realised that by dereferncing a cursor (however that was done) still allows acces to the cursor to get `Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4`. you learn something everyday I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the cursor has more items, replace your while loop with this

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
       System.out.println("VARDİYA: " + cursor.getString(gunIx));
       System.out.println("TARİH: " + cursor.getString(vtarihIx));            
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: This would fail with the same issue if the Cursor were empty.